# Run Time Error '13' on VBA - How do I solve this?

Tags: excel, vba

```
If rw.Cells > 1 Then
        If Pendingws.Cells(rw.Row, 2).Value = "" Then 'if the rw.row >1 then value of option is in pendingws rw.row, 2
            Exit For
        End If
```

the first line is what is causing the error, any ideas??

Comment: Error is probaly caused by the fact the rw is a range with more than one cell. But as you are not showing the defintion of rw and what has been assinged to rw it's just a guess.

Comment: the default member for `Cells` is the `Item(Row,Column)`. Your test makes no sense. What is it you are trying to test?

Comment: I guess you are trying this? `If rw.Cells.Count > 1 Then`

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
If rw.Cells
```

to

```
If rw.Cells.Count
```